# Need help installing CiviCRM on backdrop CMS

Tags: install, backdrop, setup

I'm starting a social work, family help and education center in Germany (empathus-erziehungshilfen.de). I would love to work with CiviCRM to document cases and spent time for me and my employees. I tried to install backdrop CMS (as well as WP and Drupal) but I couldn't really get it to work properly. Everything within CiviCRM I can do on my own, it's only a proper installation and initial setup for CiviCRM to work as it should. I am searching for a good-hearted CiviCRM pro who would help me install it. I'll provide the SFTP login and everything that's needed. We are a non-profit organization and I don't have much money to spend but I could afford $50 for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!

Have you looked at [CiviCRM Spark](https://civicrm.com/)?  Just sign up and start using it.

Alternatively you can find a list of [partners in Germany](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?custom_181=All&country_id=1082&custom_157=All&cms=All) or globally who undertake paid work on CiviCRM.

Also, just checking you have found the [installation guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/)